# Determine $M$ for Simpson's rule error bound

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

$2e^x + x^3$ where $a = 0$ and $b = 1.6$, for this equation how would you determine the Simpson's rule error bound. specifically how would one determine $M$. its confusing to me as the graph on the interval $(0,1.6)$ is $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your last sentence; clarification would be nice there.

Anyway, the Simpson rule error estimate says that if $n$ is even and you use $n+1$ evaluation points, then the error in the integration is at most

$$\frac{\max_{x \in [a,b]} |f''''(x)|}{180 n^4} (b-a)^5.$$

In your case, $f''''(x)$ is very simple, it is just $2 e^x$. This is increasing, so its maximum occurs at the right endpoint. Can you take it from here?

Comment: what i meant by the last sentence was that the gradient was 0 on the interval. so i was just wondering were the max value would be. what would the value for M be, thats what i want to know. The equation you used for the error is a bit differnt to the one i used. i used the $\1/180(b-a)Mh^4

Comment: where h is the interval length

Comment: @mandem But it isn't zero, where are you getting that it is zero? Your value of $M$ should be $2 e^{1.6}$, that is, the value of $f''''$ at the right endpoint (because $|f''''|=f''''$ is increasing). Your estimate is the same as mine, just rearranged somewhat.

Comment: its fine now, i was getting confused by looking at the graph of the curve. it wasn't increasing on the interval so i was getting confused. also i had one more question, i know Simpson's rule is O(h^4) so if i double the number what type of change/ratio should i expect.

Comment: @mandem If you double the number of intervals then you will multiply the error by $(1/2)^4=1/16$.